# Threading/Async in Requests-html

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-requests

I have a large number of links I need to scrape from a website. I have ~70 base links and from them over 700 links that need to be scraped from those starting 70. So in order to speed up this process, takes about 2-3 hours without threading/async, I decided to try and use a thread/async.

My problem is that I need to render some javascript in order to get the links in the first place. I have been using requests-html to do this as its html.render() method is very reliable. However, when I try and run this using threading or async I run into a host of problems. I tried AsyncHTMLSession due to this [Github PR](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html/pull/146)  but have been unable to get it to work. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas or links they could point me too that might help.

Here is some example code:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

links = (tuple of links)
n = 5
batch = [links[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(links), n)]


def link_processor(batch_link):
    session = AsyncHTMLSession()
    results = []

    for l in batch_link:
        print(l)
        r = session.get(l)
        r.html.arender()
        tmp_next = r.html.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/matches/")]')

    return tmp_next


pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)

output = pool.map(link_processor, batch)
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(output)
```

Output:

```
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

Was able to fix this with some help from the learnpython subreddit. Turns out requests-html probably uses threads in some way and so threading the threads has an issue so simply using multiprocessing pool works.

FIXED CODE:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from requests_html import HTMLSession

.....

pool = Pool(processes=3)
output = pool.map(link_processor, batch[:2])
pool.close()
pool.join()
print(output)
```